# undefined behavior when casting template holding a polymorphic type

Tags: c++, gcc, polymorphism, undefined-behavior, type-erasure

For reasons of type erasure I have a template `A<T>` which can hold any datatype. When `A` holds a polymorphic type `Derived` which is derived from `Base` and I cast it to `A<Base>`, GCC's undefined behavior sanitizer reports runtime errors:

```
#include <iostream>

struct I
{
    virtual ~I() = default;
};

template<typename T> 
struct A : public I
{
    explicit A(T&& value) : value(std::move(value)) {}
    T& get() { return value; }
private:
    T value;
};

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void fun() 
    {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    void fun() override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    I* a_holding_derived = new A<Derived>(Derived());
    A<Base>* a_base = static_cast<A<Base>*>(a_holding_derived);
    Base& b = a_base->get();
    b.fun();
    return 0;
}
```

**compile & run**

```
$ g++ -fsanitize=undefined -g -std=c++11 -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer && ./a.out
```

**output:**

```
main.cpp:37:62: runtime error: downcast of address 0x000001902c20 which does not point to an object of type 'A'

0x000001902c20: note: object is of type 'A<Derived>'

 00 00 00 00  20 1e 40 00 00 00 00 00  40 1e 40 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  21 00 00 00

              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

              vptr for 'A<Derived>'

    #0 0x400e96 in main /tmp/1450529422.93451/main.cpp:37

    #1 0x7f35cb1a176c in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2176c)

    #2 0x400be8  (/tmp/1450529422.93451/a.out+0x400be8)


main.cpp:38:27: runtime error: member call on address 0x000001902c20 which does not point to an object of type 'A'

0x000001902c20: note: object is of type 'A<Derived>'

 00 00 00 00  20 1e 40 00 00 00 00 00  40 1e 40 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  21 00 00 00

              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

              vptr for 'A<Derived>'

    #0 0x400f5b in main /tmp/1450529422.93451/main.cpp:38

    #1 0x7f35cb1a176c in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2176c)

    #2 0x400be8  (/tmp/1450529422.93451/a.out+0x400be8)


Derived
```

**<kbd>[live example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/802755edf1b4da6d)</kbd>**

I have two questions:

1. Is the sanitizer's output correct?
2. If yes, how would a valid conversion from `A<Derived>`to `A<Base>` look like?

Comment: The static cast from `I*` to `X` has undefined behaviour since it is actually pointing to a subobject of `Y`, and `X` and `Y` are different types (respectively `A<Base>` and `A<Derived>`).

Comment: This isn't what people usually mean by "type erasure". Type erasure would have a single, (non-template) type `A` which you could *construct* from arbitrary types. The polymorphism would be in the private parts. Examples of type erasure in the standard library are `std::function` and `std::experimental::any`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I do have another type which wraps around `A`; I did not show it here to keep the example minimal.

Comment: OK - in that case, you must use `I` exclusively as your "type-erased handle". Every semantic aspect of your public API must be implementable through `I`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I could use two nested `static_cast`s, but then I would need to know the original type (which defeats the purpose of type erasure somehow): [example code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/904a6d48aa732fa7); is there any way around that?

Comment: I'm not sure that the problem is well-defined. Type erasure doesn't give you magic powers. It solves very *specific* problems that need to be encoded in the interface. For example, `any` is the simplest example of a type-erasing class, whose only interface is "type checking". `std::function` is a different type-erasing class whose interface is "function call operator". You need to have an interface in mind that you want to provide in a type-erased way. Since your `I` is empty, you are not accomplishing anything at the moment.

Comment: I can post a representative example for what type erasure normally looks like if you like, and you could see if  you can fit your needs into it?

Comment: @KerrekSB yes please, that would be really great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `A<Base>` and `A<Derived>` do not have any relation to each other *at all*. They may be represented entirely differently. For the cast you are trying to do it would be necessary that `A<Base>` is a base class of `A<Derived>` which is clearly not the case.

It seems, you want to create something like a smart pointer which behaves like a value type. Off-hand, I'm not sure whether a value type can be created which supports all the necessary conversions supported. If there are specific needs or a known common base class in groups of types for which conversions need to be supported a corresponding class can be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about your design goals, but to put the discussion in perspective, here's a typical example of type erasure: A single class `Foo` that exposes an erased invocation of `bar`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

class Foo
{
    struct ImplBase
    {
        virtual ~ImplBase() = default;
        virtual int bar(int, int) = 0;  // This line is the whole point!
    };

    std::unique_ptr<ImplBase> impl;

    template <typename T> struct Impl : ImplBase
    {
        Impl(T t) t_(std::move(t)) {}

        int bar(int a, int b) override { return t_.bar(a, b); }

        T t_;
    };

public:
    template <typename T>
    Foo(T && x)
    : impl(new Impl<typename std::decay<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(x)))
    {}

    int bar(int a, int b)  // Not virtual! Foo is a "value-like" class.
    {
        return impl->bar(a, b);
    }
};
```

The utility in such an approach lies in the fact that you can now have a single interface type that uses `Foo`, and you can call this interface with *any* type that structurally meets the requirements of `Impl` (which you would of course document without reference to the implementation details).

For example, consider the following function:

```
void DoSomething(Foo a, int x, int y)
{
    UpdateCounter(a.bar(x, y));
}
```

This function can be defined and compiled in one single translation unit, never to be touched again. But future users, who may never have been in causal contact with the `DoSomething` author, can pass arbitrary objects that expose a `bar` function in:

```
struct X { double bar(long int, int); };
struct Y { char bar(int, float, bool = false); };

DoSomething(Foo(X{}), 10, 20);
DoSomething(Foo(Y{}), 20, 10);
```

Notes:

- Type erasure provides *ad-hoc polymorphism*.
- Requirements on client types are structural, not inheritance-related. Think "duck typing" or "concept".
- The type-erased design exposes *functionality*, not hierarchical relatedness.
- You can make `Foo` copyable if you require that `Impl` be copiable (which translates to a requirement on `T`).
- We use raw `new`; there's no allocator support. Type-erasing allocator support has been proving very challenging, especially if the type-erased state is supposed to be copyable.